# How to get total amount of orders and count of invoices?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a reports section that gets some reports about users, so I need to get the total amount of orders that `users bought from merchant` then how many invoices that user have with a specific merchant

my query:

```
SELECT
    users.id,
    users.name,
    users.number,
    users.created_at,
    SUM(orders.billing_total) AS total_amount,
    MIN(orders.created_at) AS first_order_date,
    count(DISTINCT (invoices.id)) AS invoices_count
FROM
    users
    INNER JOIN invoices ON invoices.user_id = users.id
    INNER JOIN orders ON orders.user_id = users.id
WHERE
    invoices.merchant_id = 15
    AND invoices.user_id = 11
    AND orders.merchant_id = 15
    AND orders.user_id = 11
GROUP BY
    users.id
ORDER BY
    created_at DESC
```

I tested this on a user that has two orders from a merchant with `15` and the right total_amount is 187.00 but when I run the query I got `989.18`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggregate before joining:

```
SELECT u.*, o.total_amount, o.first_order_date, i.invoices_count
FROM users u JOIN
     (SELECT i.user_id, COUNT(*) as invoices_count
      FROM invoices i
      GROUP BY i.user_id
     ) i
     ON i.user_id = u.id JOIN
     (SELECT o.user_id, MIN(o.created_at) AS first_order_date, 
             SUM(o.billing_total) AS total_amount
      FROM orders o
      GROUP BY o.user_id
     ) o
     ON o.user_id = u.id;
ORDER BY o.created_at DESC;
```

If you do need to filter, you can filter appropriately in the subqueries.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Can you please provide the filter example just need these columns `'users.id', 'users.created_at', 'users.name','users.number',`

Comment: @user16390519 . . . If you are filtering only on `users`, you can put the filter in the outer query.